# F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)

Tags: firemonkey, rad

There is a problem. I am writing code Rad Studio in multi device application. When I compile the programme in Android debug,I am getting an error.

Error : [DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)

What should I do?

Thank you in advice.

Comment: Have you tried to right-click the project and choose "Clean", and then rebuild it?

Comment: Please mark my answer as the correct answer

Comment: @Hans In my solution not working right-click the project and choose "Clean", any other solution. Tnx

Answer (score 4):

This might be solved if you right-click the project and choose "Clean". Then rebuild the project.

There can be many reasons for a linker error. The first thing to try is always to "Clean" the project because Delphi can get out of sync with the compiled units. However, if that does not solve it then you can expand the "Linker error" message (or usually it is the adjacent message) and see what caused the linking to fail. For each individual reason there might be another SO question with exactly that problem.

Comment: @AbdullahIlgaz Do you fix problem and how?

Comment: @Pointer Try to delete output directory for needed platform then clean your project, rebuild it. If its not fixed, close your Rad Studio and re-run as administrator then do the same things.

Comment: @OmarReis I expanded the answer

Comment: @Hans you're an Angel. Cleaning is simply the solution. thank you so much.